# How do I "mount" docker image in another mount?

Tags: docker

How do I put docker images in another mount? I would like docker image x to be on /dev/sda and image y on /dev/sdb.  How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know much. But if lxc supports this feature, docker should support it.

Answer (score 0):

I think at this point, you can't get Docker to do this - you'd be best off asking on irc.freenode.net in the #docker-dev channel (though right now alot of devs are away at DockerConEU)